# как задержать выполнение скрипта до получения ответа от сервера

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
var num = '';
window.uid = '';

//function getId(){
 
(function($){
 num = $('#statUid').data('uid');
 
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://......./file.php',
  data: {
   'num': num
  },
  success: function(response) {
   uid = response;
   console.log('внутри ajax: '+uid);
  },
  error: function() {
   //
   console.log('ошибка!');
  }
 });
 
})(jQuery);

//};// end getID
console.log('после ajax: '+uid);
//setTimeout(function(){
 
var _paq = _paq || [];
/* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
_paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.domain + "/" + document.title]); //добавиляет поддомены
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
_paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
(function() {
var u="//widget.minsocium.ru/modules/stat/";
_paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
 //----
// getId();
 console.log('в piwik коде: '+num);
 console.log('в piwik коде: '+uid);
 //----
_paq.push(['setSiteId', uid]); //'1'
var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
})();

 
//}, 1000);
```

Как сделать, чтоб начинающийся с `var _paq = _paq || [];` или хотябы ниже где `//----` не выполнялся, а ждал ответа от сервера, для получения значения переменной `uid`. Оборачивать данный код ни во что нельзя, не будет работать. Подскажите, что можно предпринять в данной ситуации.  p.s. закоменченные строки, это пробовал различные варианты.

```js
var num = '';
window.uid = '';

(function($){
 var post = $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'http://............/file.php',
     data: {
      'num': num
     }
    });

 post.done(function(response){
  uid = response;
  console.log('внутри ajax: '+uid);

  var _paq = _paq || [];
  /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
  _paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.domain + "/" + document.title]); //добавиляет поддомены
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
  var u="//widget.minsocium.ru/modules/stat/";
  _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
   //----
  // getId();
   console.log('в piwik коде: '+num);
   console.log('в piwik коде: '+uid);
   //----
  _paq.push(['setSiteId', uid]); //'1'
  var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
 });

 post.fail(function(){
   //Обработка ошибок
  alert("error!");
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: почему не будет работать, если оборачивать? не оборачивая никак.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать промисы. `$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  alert( jqXHR.status ); // Alerts 200
});`

Comment: я не могу понять почему не работает в обертке. это piwik - аналитика сайта. подключаю данный код файлом, а не сразу вставляю в head. пытаюсь рыть в файлах piwik, но пока не нашел, где формируется данный код у них.  Пробовал обернуть в setTimeout, переменная приходит в нужный момент в итоге, но скрипт сам не отрабатывает, статистика не приходит.

Comment: "Оборачивать ... нельзя, не будет работать" - какие-то Ваши переменные, объявленные в глобальной области видимости, после оборачивания из нее исчезают. Найдите их и почините.

Comment: Возможно проблема с `var _paq = _paq || [];` попробую объявить ее заранее, как глобальную.

Comment: кому нужна переменная `_paq`?

Comment: piwik ее использует, массив передает. пробовал ее объявлять в другом месте - не работает.

Comment: "объявлять в другом месте" - Вы думаете, мне это о чем-то говорит?

Comment: пробовал объявлять в начале кода, там же где `var num = '';
window.uid = '';`, если объявлять через `var`, то не работает просто, а если через `window`, то ругается, что писал уже не помню. но именно на эту строчку ругался

Comment: "что писал уже не помню" - так напишите еще раз и "вспомните". Кто у кого просит помощи?

Comment: если в начале пишу `window._paq;`, потом весь код оборачиваю в jquery и в нутри ``, то пишет ошибку `Uncaught ReferenceError: _paq is not defined`, если в начале пишу `window._paq = _paq || [];` , то та же ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Сложно проверить на работоспособность, попробуйте поработать с минимальным кол-вом переменных и манипуляций с ними. Если все получается, то идите дальше и добавляйте функционал

```js
(function($){
 var num = $('#statUid').data('uid');
 var post = $.ajax({
     url: "http://......./file.php",
     data: {'num': num} ,
     type: "POST"
 });

 post.done(function(response){
  var uid = response;

  var _paq = _paq || [];
  /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
  _paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.domain + "/" + document.title]); //добавиляет поддомены
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);

  var u = "//widget.minsocium.ru/modules/stat/";
  _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u + 'piwik.php']);
  _paq.push(['setSiteId', uid]); //'1'
  
  var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), 
      s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

  g.type='text/javascript'; 
  g.async=true; 
  g.defer=true; 
  g.src=u+'piwik.js'; 
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s); 
 });

 post.fail(function(){
   //Обработка ошибок
     alert("error!");
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: К сожалению так вообще не работает, пример того, что сделал добавлю в вопрос. Посмотрите, может я что-то не так понял? И ведь получается в обертке все, даже не один раз ((

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такой выход. Разделил код в разные файлы. В файле с моим кодом внутри ajax, после получения переменной вызываю функцию подключающую файл с кодом piwik.

Comment: А другие ответы совсем не помогли?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Вся проблема в том, что код piwik не работает в любой обертке, в чем причина я не понял, вынос переменных из обертки не помог.   Но всем, кто откликнулся огромное спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать идентификатор завершения запроса (в данном случае `done`) и проверять его либо по таймеру, либо в рекурсии, либо в бесконечном цикле. Когда он станет в состоянии "запрос выполнен" (`true` в нашем случае) можно выполнять все что хотите дальше.

```
var num = '';
window.uid = '';

var done = false; // <----------------------------------

//function getId(){

(function($){
    num = $('#statUid').data('uid');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://......./file.php',
        data: {
            'num': num
        },
        success: function(response) {
            uid = response;
            console.log('внутри ajax: '+uid);
            done = true; // <----------------------------------
        },
        error: function() {
            //
            console.log('ошибка!');
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

//};// end getID
console.log('после ajax: '+uid);
var intId = setInterval(function(){ // <----------------------------------

  if(done) { // <----------------------------------
    var _paq = _paq || [];
    /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
    _paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.domain + "/" + document.title]); //добавиляет поддомены
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);

    (function() {
    var u="//widget.minsocium.ru/modules/stat/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
      //----
    //  getId();
      console.log('в piwik коде: '+num);
      console.log('в piwik коде: '+uid);
      //----
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', uid]); //'1'
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();
    clearInterval(intId); // <----------------------------------
  } // <----------------------------------
}, 1000); // <----------------------------------
```

Через `while`

```
var num = '';
window.uid = '';

var done = false; // <----------------------------------

//function getId(){

(function($){
    num = $('#statUid').data('uid');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://......./file.php',
        data: {
            'num': num
        },
        success: function(response) {
            uid = response;
            console.log('внутри ajax: '+uid);
            done = true; // <----------------------------------
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('ошибка!');
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

//};// end getID
console.log('после ajax: '+uid);

while(!done) { // <----------------------------------
    var _paq = _paq || [];
    /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
    _paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.domain + "/" + document.title]); //добавиляет поддомены
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);

    (function() {
        var u="//widget.minsocium.ru/modules/stat/";
        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
        //----
        //  getId();
        console.log('в piwik коде: '+num);
        console.log('в piwik коде: '+uid);
        //----
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', uid]); //'1'
        var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();
} // <----------------------------------
```

Но если использовать `fetch` или какую то либу которая возвращает промис то все можно сделать еще короче и понятней. Конечно при условии что Вы использоете какой то транспилятор (например `babel`).

Можно попробовать что то типа такого (писал с блокнота, нужно потестить)

```
let num = '';
let uid = '';

(async () => {    
    num = document.getElementById('statUid').data('uid');      
    uid = await fetch("http://......./file.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: {num}
    })    
    let _paq = _paq || [];
    /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
    _paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.domain + "/" + document.title]); //добавиляет поддомены
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);

    let u="//widget.minsocium.ru/modules/stat/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
     //----
    //  getId();
    console.log('в piwik коде: '+num);
    console.log('в piwik коде: '+uid);
    //----
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', uid]); //'1'
    var d = document,
        g = d.createElement('script'),
        s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript';
    g.async=true;
    g.defer=true;
    g.src=u+'piwik.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);

})();
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но как писал выше, любая обертка делает код piwik не рабочим.

Comment: ну так идите через цикл а не через интервал (правда тут вопрос в потреблении ресурсов) добавил вариант в ответ

Comment: Так там тоже обертка получается! Код начинающийся на `var _paq = _paq || [];` нельзя оборачивать. Спасибо еще раз за попытку помочь, вопрос решил своим способом, может и можно более правильно, но других вариантов не нашлось.

Answer (score -1):

Сделайте запрос синхронным . Параметр в запросе:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://......./file.php',
    data: {
        'num': num
    },
    success: function(response) {
        uid = response;
        console.log('внутри ajax: '+uid);
        done = true; // <----------------------------------
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('ошибка!');
    }
});
```

Вот параметр, который нужно добавить в `ajax` запросе -  `async:false`
и программа будет ожидать получения данных с сервера